# How do I change the URL format of news items in the Composite C1 news package?

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, c1-cms

I installed the `Composite.News` package in Composite C1. The URL format of the news items is by default:

```
/PageName/YYYY/MM/DD/NewsItemName
```

I wish to remove the date part of the url ("/YYYY/MM/DD"). I cannot find a setting for it and I don't know where it's specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no settings to change this, the only way is to re-write the source code for this package which can be downloaded from here  - http://c1packages.codeplex.com/